# Installing Mesa on ubuntu

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, vtk, mesa

I am trying to install and use VTK on my 32-bit linux machine (EC2 instance on AWS).
I was getting an error which i realized was because I did not have openGL/Mesa installed on my machine.
So i installed Mesa using the following command: sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
Now, I dont know where mesa is installed on my machine. There is no folder 'mesa' in /usr/lib/ and there is no libGl.so anywhere.
Can anybody tell me how to proceed further?

Comment: `sudo dpkg -L mesa-common-dev`?

Comment: What is distro/gpu on that configuration? How do you expect any useful help without such info? And mesa-common-dev will not install gpu drivers for you...